# React Redux JWT pause async request before start a new one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jwt, middleware

Ok, so helo guys, it's my first post here, because I am desperated so much I will ask you for help. 
I've got a problem with async request in redux-thunk. 
Look:
I have react-redux-jwt authentication and I'm blacklisting old token on every request and with express middleware I'm sending a new one for requesting user. And when user ask a server with one of expired tokens (marked in database) then BOOM -> 401. **BUT** everything is fine, when my dispatching looks like this:

```js
// imports
class Components extends React.Component {

  // ...rest

  firstTrigger(data) {
    const {dispatch} = this.props;
    dispatch(anyActions.firstAction(data));
  }

  secondTrigger(data) {
    const {dispatch} = this.props;
    dispatch(anyOtherActions.secondAction(data));
  }

  render() {
    return <div >
      // ... rest
        <button onClick={this.firstTrigger}> Trigger 1 </button> 
        <button onClick={this.secondTrigger}> Trigger 2 </button> 
      </div>;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

And fun begins when I've got to run some actions in one moment like this:

```js
// imports
    class Components extends React.Component {

      // ...rest

      anyTrigger(data) {
        const {dispatch} = this.props;
        dispatch(anyActions.firstAction(data));
        dispatch(anyOtherActions.secondAction(data));
      }

      render() {
        return <div >
          // ... rest
            <button onClick={this.anyTrigger}> Trigger two actions </button> 
          </div>;
      }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

And now you guys propably guess whats going on there. First query going to server with custom axios request (with token ofc.), everything is fine, so it's do what I want, gets a new token and blacklists an old one and going to return with a brand new token **AND THEN** second action was dispatched and sended with old token (the same as was at first action), but this token was already blacklisted by first request and BOOM -> 401. I'm mad because of this. I'm tried almost everything: custom queue packages, flags in custom state, redux middlewares, sagas, buffering actions at middleware level...
Maybe it is a stupid question, but I'm grown in PHP and I have no idea how to solve this. Maybe you have any other secure way to handle JWT with react-redux? Or you have some ideas how to pause request till the previous one ends? 
 Oh, and sorry for my english, but I think you should understand what I've got to say.

Answer (score 1):

Solved,
I Just stopped using redux middleware, and install interceptor from https://gist.github.com/mkjiau/650013a99c341c9f23ca00ccb213db1c Best solution at the moment for me.

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.